# rails association involving keys of different types

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, has-many

I have two tables with schemas:

```
create_table "posts"
end

create_table "comments" do |t|
  t.string post_id
end
```

My problem is that `Post.includes(:comments)` results in a postgres error:

```
  ERROR:  operator does not exist: character varying = integer
                                                       ^
  HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s).
  You might need to add explicit type casts
```

It's because Post.id is an integer and Comments.post_id is a string and postgres won't auto-cast INTEGER to VARCHAR.

The obvious solution is to make Post.id and Comment.post_id the same type, but I don't want to do that because Comments comes from a separate gem (ActiveAdmin) and I don't want to change my Post.id to a string.

In rails 3, I could use has_many :finder_sql to make this work via an explicit cast.

With finder_sql deprecated in Rails 4, is there any way to make this work?

Comment: *"I don't want to change my Post.id to a string."* Did you consider changing Comment.post_id to an integer? That would seem to be the Rails thing to do.

Comment: I don't have any control over the key in Comments, see [here](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/9cfc45330e5ad31977b3ac7b2ccc1f8d6146c73f/lib/generators/active_admin/install/templates/migrations/create_active_admin_comments.rb#L6).  And as you and @NibbleX have pointed out, it'd be ugly to change Post.id to a string.